# Tried to change my username, now the user isn't at the log in options

Tags: ubuntu, users

I was trying to change my username. I oppened the terminal and if I remember correctly I used
`sudo /etc/shadow`
and
`sudo /etc/passwd`
Then i saw it didn't change, so I made a temporary user, logged in and used the command

```
sudo usermod -l newusername -d /home/newusername -m oldusername
```

and when I logged in again and saw that it didn't change anything

```
sudo usermod -l newusername oldusername
```

Then I tried some more stuff that I don't remember and resterted my computer. And there was only the temporary user. I logged in and I could find the files of the original user but I can't log into the account. Is there anything I could do?

Comment: `sudo /etc/passwd` and `sudo /etc/shadow` should have given you errors since those two files are not commands. Exactly what commands did you run and what was the output? Without that, we're just guessing.

Comment: I honestly don't remember, I tried a lot of things and i'm a noob. I definitely  ran something that ended with /passwd and /shadow and the terminal sowed some information about the user, it had lines with a title like bin and then some numbers and i changed the username there

Answer (score 0):

Some of the bellow commands will not work because you already changed the user so just follow the steps and see what works for you. Like @doneal24 said this is just a guessing so you have to check all the possible variants. Let us know how what worked for you.

##### Steps to change the username:

Define the variables

```
new_username=newUSER
old_username=oldUSER
```

Check the ID if the old user

```
id ${old_username}
```

Rename the user and home directory

```
usermod -d /home/${new_username} ${old_username}
usermod -l ${new_username} ${old_username}
```

Change the group

```
groupmod --new-name ${new_username} ${old_username}
```

Change the mail folder and owner (just in case usermod did not changed it)

```
mv /var/spool/mail/{${old_username},${new_username}}
chown ${new_username} /var/spool/mail/${new_username}
```

Check the ID of the new user

```
id ${new_username}
```

Rename home folder (in case usermod did not renamed it)

```
mv /home/{${old_username},${new_username}}
```

Check the rename was done

```
ls -la /home
```

Change /etc/passwd user homedir manually (in case usermod did not changed it)

```
grep "${old_username}" /etc/passwd 
nano /etc/passwd
```

Change user on ssh public key manually (by default the ssh key stores the user it created it, we want the new username instead)

```
grep "${old_username}" /home/${new_username}/.ssh/*.pub
nano /home/${new_username}/.ssh/*.pub
```

Change user on visudo manually (optionally)

```
visudo
```